# R code list variables in the order they appear

Tags: r

I am just trying to get R to give me a list of all the variables in my dataframe, but not have it be alphabetical.

I tried `ls(df, sorted = FALSE)` but it says unused argument.

Comment: How about `names(df)` ?

Comment: maybe `colnames(df)`?

Answer (score 0):

`ls()` is used to list the objects in an environment. It also does not have a `sorted` argument, as it returns the values sorted by default.  For a data frame, you can use `names` to get the names of the column variables.  But you can also use `ls()` if you use `with` to create an environment with the data frame

```
> with(mtcars, ls())
 [1] "am"   "carb" "cyl"  "disp" "drat" "gear" "hp"  
 [8] "mpg"  "qsec" "vs"   "wt"
```

And `names` does not sort the variable names

```
> names(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec"
 [8] "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized my data was pulling through the API alphabetically, so that was part of the problem I was having as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get all the variable names and the internal object structure by using

`str(df)`